# Middle/Guard relay:WARN Bad password or authentication cookie on controller WARN Your server has not managed to confirm reachability for its ORPort(s)

Tags: configuration, relays, ubuntu, server, nyx

OS: Ubuntu Server 22.04.2

I'm running a tor relay on an old laptop. I'm managing it on my main computer with ssh. From my perspective this is ideal because in theory I could manage multiple nodes from one device, nice and simple. However I am a noob and don't know if this is a security risk or not. I'm getting the following warnings after following the tutorial at torproject.org. Does anyone know what going on?
`/etc/tor/torrc`

```
SocksPort 0
ControlPort 9051
HashedControlPassword 16:...
ORPort 443
ExitPolicy reject *:*
```

Can't find any clear answers about the following warns from `/var/log/tor/notices.log`

```
[WARN] Bad password or authentication cookie on controller.
[WARN] Your server has not managed to confirm reachability for its ORPort(s) at 111.1.1.1 Relays do not publish descriptors until their ORPort and DirPort are reachable. Please check your firewalls, ports, address, /etc/hosts file, etc.
```

Comment: what's the OS you're managing your relay(s) from?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> [WARN] Bad password or authentication cookie on controller.
> ```

You (or someone) tried to access tor's control port, but the authentication failed (probably the wrong password).

Is your control port accessible only over SSH, or have you also made it publicly accessible on the Internet? Unless you changed `ControlListenAddress`, then the default is just localhost.

> ```
> [WARN] Your server has not managed to confirm reachability for its ORPort(s) at 111.1.1.1 Relays do not publish descriptors until their ORPort and DirPort are reachable. Please check your firewalls, ports, address, /etc/hosts file, etc
> ```

The relay can't confirm that other devices on the Internet can access your relay. Specifically, it seems that they can't connect to port 443 on your laptop. Are you sure there is no firewall preventing access to this port from the Internet (either a firewall on the system or on your router)? And I'm assuming that you changed the IP address to "111.1.1.1" when you posted it here, but are you sure that the original IP was correct?

Comment: I do not have anything configured for `ControlListenAddress`. I'm just using `ssh hostname@ip-adress` to access the server. I am not the admin of the network, so it could very well be a router issue. However I would like to try everything that I can on my side first, how would I change the firewall settings? Also I only used the host ip-address to ssh into the machine otherwise I have not specified the ip anywhere in `/etc/tor/torrc` or any other config file.

Comment: On Ubuntu a popular tools is [ufw](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-20-04) to configure the firewall. If you haven't configured a firewall yet, then there probably is no firewall on your system. On your router you'll need to enable port forwarding so that incoming connections from the Internet on port 443 will be redirected to port 443 on your laptop.